# Spring MVC returns 404 in production for some requests but works fine in all other envs

Tags: spring-mvc

We have the following combination in our application.

- Spring mvc + tiles as view resolver + controller mapping (Request mapping)
- Docker to run our application
- Splunk to check the logs (developers dont have access to login to the server and check the logs)

We are trying to hit the following URL in Production which gives 404 in the network tab but it works fine in all other envs (there was one request which was successful in production using the same URL). All other URLs are working fine in production.

- https://host:port/context_name/assignUpdate.do

Here is the code for the same.

### web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

### dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:component-scan base-package="we have correct package mentioned here" />
```

### SomeController.java

```
@Controller
    public class SomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "assignUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView assignCampaignUpdate(formparam form, HttpSession session){
        method body
    }
 }
```

**Points to be considered**

- How about adding @ModelAttribute before formparam (not sure that will make any difference)
- formparam has a member var which is a List of some other class which has all primitives (the volume of some other class goes huge around 1.2K in production whereas in the other envs it will be around 50) - also tried this one by bringing down the search to one item in UI and sent the request. din work

Any help here

**Request Headers**

1. Accept: */*
2. Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
3. Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
4. Connection: keep-alive
5. Content-Length: 993
6. Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

**Only log which i could get**

[logtype=access] x_client_ip="ip" date="[09/Aug/2018:07:27:09 -0400]" http_status="404" content_length=0 referer="https://localhost:port/context_name/mainpage.do" user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" method=POST uri="/context_name/assignUpdate.do" query="" protocol=HTTP/1.1 durationms=55 fsreqid=- srcip=10.42.247.20

Comment: can anyone answer this ? please let me know, if there is any more information required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spinning my head for long time, i finally got the solution for the above problem.
The exception was IndexoutofBounds. In the request body, we are passing object with index more than 256. Since spring framework supports collection limit of 0 - 255 as index in the request body object, dispatcher servlet throws indexoutofbounds exception and returns 404 as status code for that request. To overcome this issue, we need to override the default collection limit of 256 which is provided by spring framework.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;

    @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
            dataBinder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(600);
        }
```

For more information, refer https://dzone.com/articles/spring-initbinder-for-handling-large-list-of-java